# Minimizing maximum is equivalent to minimizing sum over strictly convex set?

Tags: inequality, optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly concave function. Consider the following quantity $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R^n}$

\begin{align}
\DeclareMathOperator{\argmin}{argmin}
\mathbf{a} = \argmin\limits_{\mathbf{x} : f(\mathbf{x}) \geq 1} \max_{i= 1, \dots, n} x_i
\end{align}

and the following quantity $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$:

\begin{align}
\DeclareMathOperator{\argmin}{argmin}
\mathbf{b} = \argmin\limits_{\mathbf{x} : f(\mathbf{x}) \geq 1} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i
\end{align}

Is it true that $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{b}$? I tried to come up with a few counter examples but I could not find any so I feel like $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{b}$. Any hints?

Comment: how are a and b defined when argmin is a set?

Comment: f is strictly concave so solution to argmin is unique, unless if I’m mistaken.

Comment: Just adding a concave function doesn't mean you will get a unique solution. The maximum of a convex function over a convex set is not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f(x) = 2-x^Tx$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, so $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : f(x) \geq 1\} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^Tx \leq 1 \}$. You get $a=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and $b=\{(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})\}$.

Comment: Awesome thank you. Do you have any clue if there are any conditions I can put on the function $f$ such that $a=b$?

Comment: The maximum of a convex function over a convex set is attained at an extreme point, so you the convex hull of the minimizers in $a$ need all be at the boundary of the feasible region.